# Viewpager setcurrentitem animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

(My viewpager)

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager 
{
  public MyViewPager( Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
  {
    super( context, attrs );
    setMyScroller();
  }
  private void setMyScroller() 
  {
    try 
    {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public class MyScroller extends Scroller 
  {
    public MyScroller(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) 
    {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

(proguard-rules.pro)

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { private android.widget.Scroller mScroller; }
```

I know i give 5second. When i use finger to change page the page is change to slow(5second)

When i change the page in method: setCurrentItem(1, true); the page change too fast.
Im use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

So how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need not to extend Viewpager for scrollTime change..try this

```
private void setScrollSpeedCustomViewPager(ViewPager pager, int duration) {
        try {
            Field mScroller;
    mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            mScroller.setAccessible(true);
            FixedSpeedScroller scroller = new FixedSpeedScroller(
                    pager.getContext(), new LinearInterpolator(), duration,
                    true);
            // scroller.setFixedDuration(5000);
            mScroller.set(pager, scroller);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }
```

and from oncreate set viewpagerscrollspeed like this--
setScrollSpeedCustomViewPager(pager, 5000);